# Under what conditions does QR decomposition lead to a non-invertible upper triangular matrix?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, linear-regression

I've been reading up on [QR decomposition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154485/least-squares-regression-step-by-step-linear-algebra-computation/154514#154514) within the context of linear regression.  The predictive equation from linear regression is :

$y_{predict} = \beta X$

Where $X$ is an [N samples, p variables] matrix) and $\beta$ are the coefficients.  Following the [Normal Equations](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) approach and minimizing the square sum of the residuals, one finds that $\beta$ is :

$\beta = (X^{T} X)^{-1} X^{T} $

The problem with this that sometimes $X^{T} X$ is *not* invertible.  So it seems that QR decomposition of X may be a way around it. I.e

$X = QR$

[Using](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160025/100490) QR decomposition, the coefficients $\beta$ are :

$\beta = R^{-1}Q^{T}y$

The advantage seems obvious that it is easier to handle the upper triangular matrix, $R$, then trying to invert the possibly singular matrix $(X^{T} X)$. Regarding upper triangular matrices, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) says

> Note that a triangular matrix is invertible precisely when its
>   diagonal entries are invertible (non-zero).

**QUESTION** : Under what conditions is $R$ non-invertible when QR decomposition is done in linear regression?

Comment: How about adding some regularization? Would it be possible & allowed for your problem at hand?

Comment: I was thinking of this in terms of just a general linear regression without any penalties / loss functions.

Comment: Although, if there is some insight to be gained from adding regularization, then I guess I'd be open to that.

Comment: Adding regularization can make it invertible if that is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know from the properties of [determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant) that

$\det(X) = det(Q)det(R)$

If $X$ is a square matrix (we'll handle non-square matrices later), we know that Q will be an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).  Orthogonal matrices have [determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) equal to $1$ or $-1$.  Which means if

$\det(X) = \pm 1 \det(R) = 0$

So $\det(R) = 0$ are when $\det(X) = 0$.  This means that R is not invertible when $X$ is not full rank. Recall in a non-full rank matrix some of the rows are not linearly independent.  Below is an example of such matrix:

$X =  \begin{bmatrix}
    6 & 0 & -6 \\
    2 & 4 & 1 \\
    1 & 4 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}$

Very clearly, $row 1$ is a linear combination of $6 \times (row 2) - 6 \times (row 3)$.  This means that A is *not* full rank, its determinant is 0 (as shown above) and is thus singular.  Solving this with Python's numpy:

```
import numpy as np
>>> X = np.asarray([[6, 0, -6], [2,4,1], [1,4,2]])
>>> np.linalg.det(X)
0.0
>>> (Q,R)=np.linalg.qr(X)
>>> R
array([[ -6.40312424e+00,  -1.87408514e+00,   4.99756038e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,  -5.33739683e+00,  -4.00304762e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,  -8.88178420e-16]])
>>> np.linalg.inv(R)
array([[ -1.56173762e-01,   5.48362688e-02,  -1.12589991e+15],
       [ -0.00000000e+00,  -1.87357252e-01,   8.44424930e+14],
       [ -0.00000000e+00,  -0.00000000e+00,  -1.12589991e+15]])
```

Clearly looking at the value of $R_{3,3} \approx 0$ (likely *not* $0$ b/c of numerical artifacts form the QR solver). This leads to exploding values in $R^{-1}$.  Despite the fact that numpy 'inverted' $R$, one should be cautious of accepting such diverging values.

Another case where $R$ is not invertible, is when $X$ is an $m \times n$ matrix where $n>m$.  This is also a case where $X$ is underdetermined.  This leads to an $R$ matrix that is $m \times n$, which [will not have an inverse.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)